# php preg_replace, replace anchor href that doesn't contain this keyword

Tags: localhost, preg-replace, hyperlink

href\=\"(.*)\"

this match all links, 
what i need is to make it apply on all links except when href has localhost as a keyword on it

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regular expression does what you want:

```
href="(.*)localhost(.*)"
```

Answer (score -1):

`preg_replace("@href\\=\\\"((?:\\b[^l\\\"]|l[^o]|lo[^c]|loc[^a]|loca[^l]|local[^h]|localh[^o]|localho[^s]|localhos[^t]\\b)|[\\w&&[^\\\"]]+localhost|localhost[\\w&&[^\\\"]]+|[\\w&&[^\\\"]]+localhost[\\w&&[^\\\"]]+|[^l\\\"])+\\\"@", $replacement, $str)`